# Can you put a SSRS report into an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

Can you put an SSRS report into a asp.net web application?  I mean directly into the application.  I have to migrate an application from an older server to a new server and the report that is written with another technology keeps crapping out on me.  One co-worker has suggested to me that I rewrite the reports in SSRS.  But the application is creating it's database in code and if I have to create a separate proj I will have to start picking apart my code into two projects.  I don't have the time to do that currently.

Comment: Yes. You can run any SSRS report with a URL (including passing parameters). I suggest you start by googling "SSRS web API". In fact I don't understand why 80% of question on here can be solved by some basic googling.

Comment: As I said, I need the report to be directly within the application.  I do not want to create a separate project for this.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement to create a separate project. You just put some code in your existing project that opens a URL. Of course you need to install SSRS separately and create reports in there.

Comment: Sorry for the late delay.  I had to take some time off for personal reasons.

The application is not using a standard sql query.  While in the end, yes it is an sql database but it is connecting to it with a third party dll which includes certain logging and security features and web methods that I am not able to access.  Due to this, I need keep the datasource of the report as an object accessible in c# code.  I can't just pass the parameters to it via a url link.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do this.
One is to use RDLC files which are basically standalone SSRS reports you can embed within the application [See tutorial here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-rdlc-report-in-C-Sharp-Asp-Net/)

Another way is to embed an iFrame into your ASP application that uses the RS service [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/access-report-server-items-using-url-access?view=sql-server-ver15)

A third way (that we use) is to run some code against the SSRS SOAP service and return a DIV or HTML that we then embed into our own HTML [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-soap?view=sql-server-ver15)